# SQL Query - Using CONVERT / Format Date

Tags: sql

When I attempt to convert the current `AgreementEndDate` to 2 digit year using the following statement, I get the error noted below.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (FORMAT(b.AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1))
```

> Argument data type char is invalid for argument 1 of format function

Thanks for the assistance

```
WITH LicenseAgreement AS
(
    SELECT 
        MV.ID, AM.AgreementID, AM.AgreementEffectiveDate, AM.AgreementEndDate
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Agreement] A
    WHERE
        A.AgreementStatusName = 'Active'
) 
SELECT
    LA.ID, 
    LA.AgreementID,
    LA.AgreementEffectiveDate,
    LA.AgreementEndDate,
    MIN(CASE WHEN LA.AgreementEndDate >= CONVERT(date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND ((MONTH(LA.AgreementEndDate) >= 7 AND MONTH(LA.AgreementEndDate) <= 12)) THEN 'FY' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H1' 
            WHEN LA.AgreementEndDate >= CONVERT(date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  AND ((month(LA.AgreementEndDate) >= 1 AND month(LA.AgreementEndDate) <= 6)) THEN 'FY' + convert(VARCHAR(2), (FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H2' 
            ELSE NULL 
        END) AS 'Agreement Window'
FROM
    LicenseAgreement LA
GROUP BY
    ID, AgreementID, AgreementEndDate, AgreementEffectiveDate
```

Comment: You should be able to just use getdate right in the query. Also, you might look into using quarters rather than this monthly monkeying around.

Comment: I finally figured out the issue.  It is now with getting current date. I can use GETDATE().

Comment: can you post input and expected output?

Comment: when you go to this much trouble to get to your ass from your elbow you know you are doing it wrong.

Comment: INPUT = 2018-05-01  OUTPUT = FY17 H1

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead of the convert as you just need the year

`RIGHT(YEAR(b.AgreementEndDate), 2)`

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you very much. Here is final code snippet: 'FY' + (RIGHT(YEAR(b.AgreementEndDate), 2) - 1) + ' H1'

Comment: Glad it helped :)